# why *contact in setstate is undefined?

Tags: node.js

the fetching is working but i don't know why *contact in setstate is not defined...and browser says the map is not a function:
could you please help me in that

```
     state = { 
       contact:[]
       }



  async componentDidMount(){
     try{
        const response = await fetch('//localhost:8080/contacts/list')
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({contact:data.data})
        console.log("we got a response!!",contact)
      }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
      }
    }


render(){

  return (
    <div className="App">

      {this.state.contacts.map(item => <div key={item.id}>{item.email}</div>)} 

    </div>


  );
}}
```

And the Api is:http://localhost:8080/contacts/list

````
data: [
{
id: 1,
name: "admin",
email: "admin@example.com",
password: "a66abb5684c45962d887564f08346e8d"
},
{
id: 2,
name: "user",
email: "user@example.com",
password: "4da49c16db42ca04538d629ef0533fe8"
}
]
}```
````

Comment: there is a typo it should be `this.state.contact` instead of contacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typo, you're looking at `contacts` when you set it to be `contact`. little things!

Also, trying to call `map` on `this.state.contacts`, which appears to be undefined, should have thrown an error, which would have made this easier to find. You might want to check if your errors are visible, and if not, get them out in the open.

Comment: thanks..i edited the contacts*...but still the error ..when reload the page i see the data then disappear ...i dont know why